Как подключиться/отправить сообщение на telegram-api через прокси и на другой URL
В моей компании, прямого доступа на https://api.telegram.org нет.
Однако есть цепочка прокси, через которые я могу отправлять запросы на API.
Сейчас я делаю это простейшим способом, через curl, вот пример рабочей команды:
curl -ikv --proxy "http://172.29.181.34:3128" -X POST  http://172.30.69.79:9000:bot<token>/sendMessage?chat_id=<chat_id>&text=Hello

Как видите, запрос уходит не на https://api.telegram.org, а сначала на первый прокси http://172.29.181.34:3128, а потом на второй прокси http://172.30.69.79:9000 и с него уже, настроена переадресация на https://api.telegram.org
Как мне добиться такой работы, используя Python и библиотеку telebot?
Мне ведь недостаточно указать apihelper.proxy, так как после первого прокси, запрос будет пытаться обращаться к https://api.telegram.org
Как в данной библиотеке подменить конечный адрес? Или подскажите другие библиотеки для работы с telegram-api, где это возможно.
import telebot

apihelper.proxy = {'http':'http://172.29.181.34:3128'}
bot=telebot.TeleBot('token')

@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
def main(message):
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, f'Привет!  message.from_user.first_name}')


А почему нельзя общаться вебхуками, перенаправляя запросы куда надо.

Вебхуки для метода sendMessage ? Я же хочу отправить сообщение боту, а не получить от API вебхук с уведомлением, о команде, которую пользователь боту отправил.

Сам нашел рабочий вариант:
В библиотеке telebot тредактировал файл apihelper.py
Вместо:
API_URL = None

Сделал:
API_URL = 'http://172.30.69.79:9000/bot{0}/{1}'

Также, не забудьте, добавить:
from telebot import apihelper

